# Installing multiple java versions on Unix

Tags: java, linux, unix, tomcat

Does installing JDK 1.7 remove JDK 1.5? Because when I tried to restart Tomcat which was using Java 1.5 I have got the below error:

```
/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: line 332: /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Verified that this directory is gone. Tomcat services running fine until shutting down and attempting to restart last night. When trying to install Java 1.5 J have got the below error message:

```
Preparing...     ########################################### [100%]
package jdk-2000:1.7.0_17-fcs.x86_64 (which is newer than jdk -2000:1.5.0_22-fcs.x86_64) is already installed"
```

1. Will installing JDK 1.7 remove JDK 1.5?
2. How do I install JDK 1.5?

Comment: Try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jdk.html. It covers self extracting installer, you can install it anywhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you installed (which package manager or if you used the self-extracting sh or unzip).  Normally, no, they don't install over, they install alongside and simply replace symbolic links.

If you follow your symbolic links for java (which java | ls -l)... you'll find the install dir of the jdk1.7, and probably find 1.5 nearby.

Comment: So what can i do to install java 1.5 alongside as it's not allowing me to install.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the JDK from the Oracle Java archive page and you can extract it to the required location to fix your problem.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html